# RxJava - Get original input parameter in switchMap subscription

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am using Rx on Android in an editable text field. I want to retrieve the original user input in the subscription method.

I had been using [flatmap with a resultSelector parameter](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap-rx.functions.Func1-rx.functions.Func2-int-) to retain user input so far. I want to use switchMap to avoid processing results of older results. How can I migrate this code to switchMap:

```
    editText.textChanges().map { it.toString().trim() }.flatMap(
            {
                Observable.just("Data: $it")
            },
            { input: String, output: String ->
                Pair(input, output)
            }
    ).subscribe(
            process(it.first, it.second)
    )
```

Comment: Just name the argument in `switchMap` and then keep it around by composing it to whatever observable you want to return: `switchMap { v -> someSource.map { w -> Pair(v, w) } }`.

Comment: This is cool! Can you please post as an answer so that I can mark accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name the argument in switchMap and then keep it around by composing it to whatever observable you want to return:

```
switchMap { v -> someSource.map { w -> Pair(v, w) } }
```